# update price when click buttons plus or minus

Tags: jquery, html, css

here is the HTML code: (sorry if the divs are not display properly and not formated as ususal)

**HTML**

```
<form action="http://mysite.local/standard_library/view_cart" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <div class="produse-wrapper">
        <div class="header-cos">
            <div class="nr_item">
                Nr.
            </div>
            <div class="product-wrapper">
                Produs cumparat
            </div>
            <div class="pret-unitar">
                Pret unitar
            </div>
            <div class="item-cantitate">
                Cantitate
            </div>
            <div class="pret-total">
                Pret total
            </div>
            <div class="remove-item">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="order-item">
            <input type="hidden" name="items[1][row_id]" value="9fc3d7152ba9336a670e36d0ed79bc43">
            <div class="nr_item">
                1                              
            </div>
            <div class="product-wrapper">
                <div class="img-wrapper">
                    <img src="/public/thumb-98-98/2009-01-16_product.jpg">
                </div>
                <a href="http://mysite.local/category/product_133.html">
                    <div class="item-name">
                        Izolatie seminee - placi speciale 3cm                                          
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="pret-unitar">
                65.00Lei                               
            </div>
            <div class="item-cantitate">
                <div class="sp-quantity">
                    <a class="ddd" href="#" data-multi="-1">
                        <div class="sp-minus fff">-</div>
                    </a>
                    <div class="sp-input">
                        <input type="text" class="quntity-input" value="1">
                    </div>
                    <a class="ddd" href="#" data-multi="1">
                        <div class="sp-plus fff">+</div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="pret-total">
                130.00Lei                              
            </div>
            <div class="remove-item">
                <a href="/delete-item/9fc3d7152ba9336a670e36d0ed79bc43" class="remove-btn">Sterge </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-cos">
            <div class="nr_item">
            </div>
            <div class="product-wrapper">
                <div class="item-name">
                    Total
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="pret-unitar">
            </div>
            <div class="item-cantitate">
            </div>
            <div class="pret-total">
                130.00Lei                          
            </div>
            <div class="remove-item">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cart-action">
        <a href="http://mysite.local/produse.html" class="cos-btn back-comanda">Continua cumparaturile</a>
        <input type="submit" name="checkout" value="Finalizeaza comanda" class="cos-btn finalizare-comanda">
    </div>
</form>
```

what i've tried so far with jquery:

**JQUERY**

```
$(".ddd").on("click", function () {
    var $button = $(this);
    var $input = $button.closest('.sp-quantity').find("input.quntity-input");

    $input.val(function(i, value) {
        return +value + (1 * +$button.data('multi'));
        var unitar = parseInt($('.pret-unitar').val());
        var quantity = parseInt($('cantitate-input]').val());
        var total = parseInt(unitar * quantity);
    });
});
```

I want that the price to be updated when i click on plus or minus buttons. I also want that the price to be updated when i introduce the value in the input.
something like this http://jsfiddle.net/hReB3/2/

I am a noob with jquery and search though topics but it can't help me.
So please be mercy and help me! 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you using `return` in first line?

Comment: All code placed lower than return will not be executed at all.

Comment: return? what return? i don't get it..

Comment: 6th line in your JS-file.

Comment: @user3791191 I am not clear what you asking. Did you want something like this. [CLICK HERE](http://css-tricks.com/examples/InputNumberIncrementer/)

Comment: ok how should it looks like?

Comment: @ yeshansachithak no, not like that. the input already display quantity when click plus or minus

Comment: @user3791191 Please check this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yeshansachithak/FsaF2/)

Comment: checked, doesnt help..

Comment: any help? what should i do..

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#plus").on("click", function() {
   var defaultValue = parseInt($("#price").text());
   var addedValue = parseInt($("#qty").val());
    if(isNumber(addedValue) && addedValue >0) {
        $("#price").html(
            defaultValue + addedValue
        );
    }
})
```

this is my solution, please see demo http://jsfiddle.net/hReB3/20/

i build to two button bind them to query, and get the number from #price, and just add them up, and replace the original price

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=sdS9stGIq7
   i put all the code in this fiddle, i hope it will be easy to understand now.  i need when someone click the button plus or minus the quantity and the price to change too. for ex if someone add to cart a product with $30 and want another two of that product he can click the plus button and see the amount he has to pay